# how to get href value using coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

```
    <cfoutput>
        <cfsavecontent variable="s">
            This is some text. It is true that <a href="http://www.cnn.com">Harry Potter</a> is a good
        </cfsavecontent>

                <cfset matches = reMatch("<[aA].*?>",s) />
#matches#
</cfoutput>
```

I need to get only "http://www.cnn.com" how to do this

Comment: <cfset myStr = REReplaceNoCase(s, "(\bhttp://[a-z0-9\.\-_:~@##%&/?+=]+)", "<a href=""\1"">""\1""</a>", "all") />  if i use this its showing This is some text. It is true that http://www.cnn.com">Harry Potter is a good

Comment: _[USE JSOUP!](http://jsoup.org/)_

Answer (score 1):

@Bhargavi : Your regex is fine. 
Try `#matches[1]#` instead.

`<cfdump var="#matches#">` will show you the array of values on which the results can be manipulated accordingly.

Comment: The regex is _not_ fine.

Comment: CFM Code `<cfoutput>
        <cfsavecontent variable="s">
            This is some text. It is true that <a href="http://www.cnn.com">Harry Potter</a> is a good
   This is some text. It is true that <a href="http://www.test1.com">Harry Potter</a> is a good
   This is some text. It is true that <a href="http://www.test2.com">Harry Potter</a> is a good
        </cfsavecontent>

                <cfset matches = reMatch("https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?",s) />

<cfdump var="#matches#">
</cfoutput>`  gives an array of links. Am I missing something?

Comment: `<[aA].*?>` matches `<abbr>` and `<article>` and `<a name="something">` and `<a <!-- href="oldlink" -->` and various other constructs that are not what is desired.